# No vibration when receiving UILocalnotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I don't get it. This is my code where I configure my `LocalNotification` and fired it. It works fine but there is no vibration. I think there should be a vibration when I receive a Notification?

I tried AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)/        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) without no luck.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
if(state == CLRegionStateInside)
{
    notification.alertBody = @"Bla Bla";
    wasWelcomeBefore = TRUE;
}
else if(state == CLRegionStateOutside)
{
    notification.alertBody = @"Bla";
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"locationManager didDetermineState OTHER for %@", region.identifier);
    return;
}

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] != UIApplicationStateActive){
    if (!isNotifiForFirstBeacon && wasWelcomeBefore) {
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
        NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber     numberWithBool:isNotifiForFirstBeacon]                                                                    forKey:@"isFirstBeacon"];
        isNotifiForFirstBeacon = TRUE;
        notification.userInfo = dataDict;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    }
}
```

Comment: As per the docs it does state: Note that you can’t programmatically cause the device to vibrate when a notification is delivered, because the user has control over whether alerts are accompanied by vibration. See [IOS 7 HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/NotificationCenter.html)

Comment: i think you mean the         AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate); right? i insert it for testing or hoping that it work. Because at there is no vibration when a notification is fired.